# Any::hashCode function type mismatch

Tags: kotlin, type-mismatch

```
fun myHashcode() : Int{
        return 1
}

val functionRef1: () -> Int = Any::hashCode
val functionRef2: () -> Int = ::myHashcode
```

why `Any::hashCode` is not assigned in `functionRef1` with error:
`Type mismatch. Required: () → Int Found: KFunction1<Any, Int>`

but when i change the code like this(this is suggested by the IDE):

`val functionRef1: (Any) -> Int = Any::hashCode` 
then everything compiles.
Where does this `Any` parameter come from if **it is not in the signature** of the `hashCode` method in the `Any` class?

of course I know what can be done like this
`val functionRef1: KFunction1<Unit, Int> = Any::hashCode`
but I'm more interested in signature `(Any) -> Int`

Comment: The hashCode method in the Any class is actually an instance method, not a static method, this means it operates on an instance of the Any class

Comment: See the section on **method references** at https://kt.academy/article/fk-function-references

Comment: What do you try to achieve? It seems like [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: And for your question: You’re trying to say “I have a function that takes no arguments and returns an Int, and that function is Any::hashCode”. But this doesn’t match the behavior of the hashCode method, which does require an instance of Any. Hence the error.

Answer (score 1):

The correct function type signature for your `myHashCode` is, as you correctly put it, `() -> Int`. It follows the general construction rule of function type signatures in Kotlin, which is:

```
<Receiver>.(<Parameters>) -> <ReturnType>
```

When we look at your function:

```kotlin
fun myHashcode(): Int {
    return 1
}
```

It is clear that:

1. The function has no receiver type (it is neither a member function, nor an extension function)
2. The function takes no parameters
3. The function returns `Int`

When we put this all together, we get the previously mentioned function type signature.

Now, let's look at `kotlin.Any#hashCode` ([source](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/7a7d392b3470b38d42f80c896b7270678d0f95c3/core/builtins/native/kotlin/Any.kt#L43)):

```kotlin
// ...
public open class Any {
    // ...
    public open fun hashCode(): Int
}
```

Going through the signature of this function:

1. Because `hashCode` is a member of `Any`, the function has a receiver type of `Any`
2. The function takes no parameters
3. The function returns `Int`

Which means, according to the construction rule, **the correct function type for `Any::hashCode` must be `Any.() -> Int`**.

But, as IntelliJ mentioned to you, `(Any) -> Int` also seems to be a correct signature for this function. That is because function type signatures in Kotlin are interchangeable with their desugared counterparts.

The whole "receiver type" thing in Kotlin is just syntactic sugar, because on the JVM(*) there are no receiver types. Instead, extension functions on the JVM are really just functions that take one extra parameter.

And even member functions (like `kotlin.Any#hashCode`) treat their instance as a parameter when used as method references. This fact comes from Java, not Kotlin:

```java
public final class Foo {
    public static int fooParameter(Foo param) { 
        // ...
    }
    
    public int memberOfFoo() {
        // ...
    }
}

// ...

Function<Foo, Integer> first = Foo::fooParameter;
Function<Foo, Integer> second = Foo::memberOfFoo;
```

As you can see, the function type signature in Java does not discriminate between the `this` param and any arbitrary param, and the same goes for Kotlin, with the difference that Kotlin *does* have a syntactic feature to declare receiver types for function signatures. But you don't have to use it.

Meaning, that `Any.() -> Int` and `(Any) -> Int` are basically the same, or specifically, these two are both valid function signature types for the `hashCode()` member function of `Any`.

(*) The subsequently described behaviour of receiver/parameter interchangeability is most likely *caused* by Kotlin having been originally developed as a JVM language. However, as of today, Kotlin supports more platforms than just the JVM, namely Android, JS, Native and WASM (experimental). The described behaviour applies to all targets equally.

Comment: That's a great explanation. It may be worth pointing out that this behaviour is not just on the JVM, but also in all versions of Kotlin, such as Native. (It's probably behaving like this just to be compatible with the JVM, even though that is just one of the many platforms it works on.)

Comment: You are totally right, and I agree with the speculation that the behaviour on the other platforms is the same to allow for consistently behaving common code. I will add a note to my answer, thanks for pointing it out!